# Object spawning itself when other object is close enough

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

How can I make the water in my game (picture below) clone itself and put the clone right next to itself, when another object (the player) is close enough?

Scene:[scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gHOo.png)

Here is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Paralax : MonoBehaviour
{
// The player
public Transform player;

// The distance from the player needed to copy itself
public float distanceToSpawn = 30f;

// The object
public Transform trans;

bool alreadySpawned;

private void Update()
{
    if(!alreadySpawned)
    {
        // Getting the distance between
        float dst = Mathf.Abs(player.position.x - transform.position.x);
        if (dst < distanceToSpawn)
        {
            Transform newTrans = trans;
                newTrans.position = (transform.position - new Vector3(/* negative width of the water so it copies itself to the left*/-15.72f, 0f, 0f));
                Instantiate(gameObject, newTrans);
                alreadySpawned = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But for some reason the water I placed in the scene is just getting away from the player, and not copying itself. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Won't fix your problem (and also, I'm not familiar with unity) -- but what I'd do is have 2 (or more) 'water' objects, and update their position based on a calculation similar to what you've done. Will help with reducing the number of allocations...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like `trans` was maybe the same as `transform` and therefore you move this very same object away before you spawn a new clone of it as a child.

You would probably rather simply do

```
var newObj = Instantiate(gameObject, transform);
newObj.transform.position = transform.position + Vector3.left * 15.72f;
```